# Error while creating "EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE" in SQL Server 2016 version, trying to connect local SQL Server with Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am trying to connect SQL Server with Azure Data Lake using Polybase concept. While trying to create External Data Source below error is coming:

SQL Command:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureDataLakeStore_4
  WITH (
    TYPE = HADOOP,
     LOCATION = 'adl://pesdatalake1.azuredatalakestore.net',
    CREDENTIAL = [ADL_User3]
  );
```

Error:

```
 Msg 105007, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
 Scheme of the input URI is not supported. Please revise the following 
 scheme and try again: 'adl'
```

Steps followed:

1. Added Azure Data Lake in Azure portal.
2. Loaded data file to Azure data lake.
3. Did app registration, and created APP key, Auth Key and Oauth.
4. Given access to data file for App created above.
5. Created master key in SQL
6. Created a Scoped Database Credential.
7. Issue in creating External Datasource.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only supported in Azure SQL DW and not in SQL Server at this time.

Source for support statement for this feature in Azure SQL DW:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-data-lake-store

SQL Server supports Azure Blob Storage not Azure Data Lake at this time.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-azure-blob-storage